# iOS simulator uses hard disk storage a lot

Tags: ios, simulator

When I use iOS simulator, remaining hard disk capacity is decreased very much. 
I tried to check the root cause by Instrument but I couldn't find anything.
Does anyone have same issue?

Comment: `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator`

Comment: why not clean up the rest of your hard drive to give the simulator enough room to work with?  My own "`iPhone Simulator`" folder is about 5 gigs in size.

Comment: Yeah, I want to give room for it but my mac only have 12GB available. Sometimes it uses almost all remaining capacity and hangs up. After rebooting, capacity is restored but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue. I have to restart my PC which puts some recovered data into bin. Emptying bin gives me the space back.But it happens again when I use iPhone simulator.